# Привязка клавиш к управлению кнопками в WF

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Я пишу змейку на формах и у меня возникла проблема: если на форме есть **активные кнопки**, змейка больше **не реагирует на нажатие клавиш** (LEFT, DOWN, RIGHT, UP). При изменении значений кнопок Enabled на false или их удалении, проблема пропадает и управление восстанавливается.

Может есть какие-нибудь способы **"отвязать" кнопки от клавиш**?
Пока вижу только вариант замены кнопок на Label или PictureBox, но в таком случае теряется анимация, а писать ее с нуля довольно нудно.

P.S. Для управления змейкой я использую **protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)**

Comment: Попробуй в конструкторе формы написать `KeyPreview = true`. А так, если я правильно понял, проблема с фокусировкой.

Comment: А вам обязательно использовать кнопки для управления? Можете просто отлавливать нажатия необходимых кнопок через событие `KeyDown` самой формы. Либо установите `TabStop = false` у всех кнопок формы не участвующих в управлении.

Comment: TabStop помогло, спасибо.